# mysql search for keywords in phrase, orderby most keywords found

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a mysql table with 3 columns with data for a FAQ search, I want to have a user type a question they want answered and the 3 columns in the table are searched for keywords within the question that appear in any of the columns in the table. And order the results by the row that has the highest number of keyword matches.

I am using the Code Igniter framework. Currently I have a query with FULLTEXT search in my model:

```
$new_query = 'This is a question';
$sql = "SELECT ques_id, ques_desc FROM ec_questions WHERE MATCH (ques_desc,ques_tags,ques_answer) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 15";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($new_query));
return $query->result_array();
```

But the above doesn't really seem to return the results I want, help?

Thanks

"Show Create Table" Results:
http://pastebin.com/nKd1JT5n

Comment: What engine are you using for your table?  Please run "show create table ec_questions" and post the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `IN BOOLEAN MODE` as that adds support for special modifiers `+`, `-` etc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html.

Also `implode()` doesn't work directly on strings

`string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`

try

`$new_query = 'This is a question';`

instead of

`$new_query = implode(' ', 'This is a question');`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implode it looks like you want to use explode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Modified your code would look like this:

```
$new_query = explode(' ', 'This is a question');
$sql = "SELECT ques_id, ques_desc FROM ec_questions WHERE MATCH (ques_desc,ques_tags,ques_answer) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 15";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($new_query));
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Good call, there was code above what I posted that converted the string into an array, I forgot to edit that out. fixed now. :)

Comment: That was not the problem, I mean I fixed the code I posted here.